# what statistical test to use for the following research question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a general population of let's say 100,000 people, 10,000 of which are on a register following a diagnosis of kidney disease (this involves looking at a blood result and coding a diagnosis). However, I hypothesize there may be more undiagnosed people in the 100,000 general population (blood results indicates but no diagnosis code). I wish to test whether if there are people undiagnosed, is the value statistically significant. My null hypothesis is the kidney disease register is robust and there are a statistically minimal number of people undiagnosed. I'm at a loss as to what statistical test to use. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a standard null hypothesis for a statistical test; there is no such thing as "statistically minimal". You'd need to specify a maximum number that you could tolerate. But even then I wonder on the basis of what data you could find out about this. It looks like you'd need a sample from the population on which you could verify who is undiagnosed. Do you have that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can verify who is undiagnosed and diagnosed with good accuracy but view the diagnosed register as poor in it's current state and am looking to present a paper outlining this. Unfortunately I'm at a loss as to what statistical methodology to suggest in my research proposal. There are ways I can consider what would be a significant variance i.e ruling out recent tests which may have not been viewed by a clinician yet. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I properly understand the situation. So the 10,000 people on the register are all diagnosed, so not of interest for the question? You want to know how many undiagnosed people are there in the remaining 90,000 who in fact have the disease? Well, then you'd need a sample of these, and find out how many undiagnosed cases you have there. You can then run a binomial test (or the analogue for sampling without replacement) of the hypothesis that the proportion is smaller or equal to some critical proportion specified by you.

Comment: Thank you for that information, it makes sense. The diagnosed population arent of much use in the question, more the conclusion or in developing a critical proportion to be specified for the binomial test. Help has been much appreciated

Comment: OK, I made this an answer.

Comment: Do you have any outside information of how many people with condition you expect in the population? (Based for example knowledge of the condition and the demographics of the population.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 10,000 people on the register are all diagnosed, so not of interest for the question, and that you want to know how many undiagnosed people are there in the remaining 90,000 who in fact have the disease.

Then you'd need a sample of these, and find out how many undiagnosed cases you have there. You can then run a binomial test (or the analogue for sampling without replacement) of the hypothesis that the proportion is smaller or equal to some critical proportion specified by you.